# Android App Signature Developed by Someone Else for Me

Tags: android

I had someone develop an app for my nonprofit, and was about to publish the apk in the Developer Console. I realized that it needs a "release" signature by the developer. This, of course, entails key generation on the developer's part. Any recommendation on how I should publish the app under my name and my nonprofit's name?

I have paid for the app itself to be developed, and this may be a one-off scenario with this developer, but I want a key that I can use to update the app in the future using other developers.

And guidance would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the sources? Create a project in android studio, generate a keystore + key, sign the app yourself, upload to google play.

Comment: Yes, I do. That is what I was thinking. I have the .apk, the source will be given to me shortly. I was going to create the key using the key generator on Android Studio. Good idea? Thank you.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. Also read http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html and make sure to store/backup your keystore in safe places.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a key yourself. The key generator of Android Studio is perfectly fine.

Then you should compile the source yourself using the key you just generated.

Alternatively you can send the key to your developers. But unless there is a good reason I wouldn't do that because it eases identitiy theft.